# c# List of objects

Tags: c#, list

I have this class :

```
class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public _Client Client { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Accessoire> Products { get; set; }
    public int AcessoireID { get; set; }
}
```

_Client abd Accessoire are classes that have some properties ID etc ...

and i have a DataTable Filled from a Table **OrderDetails** (SQL server) 
i have 6 Rows there is some rows holds the same orderID but different accessoires properties ..

I'am using :

```
 public List<Order> AllOrders()
        {
            DataTable Table = new DataTable();
            List<Order> Orders = new List<Order>();
            Table = Browse(1,0);
            foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows)
            {
                Order item = new Order();
                    item.ID = (int)Row[0];
                    item.Date = (DateTime)Row[1];
                    item.Products = new List<Accessoire>();
                    item.Client = new Gestion.Garage.Modules._Client();
                    item.Client.ID = (int)Row[2];
                    item.Client.Name = (string)Row[9];
                    item.Client.Phone = (string)Row[10];
                    item.Client.Email = (string)Row[11];
                    item.Client.Adress = (string)Row[12];
                    item.Client.Marque = (string)Row[13];
                    item.Client.Model = (string)Row[14];
                    item.Client.Kilometrage = (string)Row[15];
                    item.Client.Anne = (string)Row[16];
                    item.Client.Obvservation = (string)Row[17];
                    item.AcessoireID = (int)Row[18];
                    Orders.Add(item);

            }
            return Orders;
        }
```

But i don't know how to Fill the List on using Foreach loop since i can't initialize the Accessoires List foreach Row Returned from the Table .

Comment: Can't use a foreach -- have use a more interesting loop where sometimes you create a new object and sometimes you don't. -- or use a foreach but keep a pointer to the prior one to see if you should update that one or make a new one.

Comment: this made an idea pops up thanks !

Comment: You could use an `IEnumerable` and use the `yield return` functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what i did was pretty simple : 
i added this

a simple function that calls a Stored procedure that gets all the Accessoire from their table by Condition (Where orderID)

```
private List<Accessoire> Accessoires(int orderID)
{
    List<Accessoire> Accessoires = new List<Accessoire>();
    DataTable Table = new DataTable();
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@orderID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[0].Value = orderID;
    Table = Method.GetData(param, "GetAccessoires");
    if (Table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(DataRow Row in Table.Rows)
        {
            Accessoire item = new Accessoire();
            item.ID = (int)Row[1];
            item.Name = GetAccessoireName((int)Row[1]);
            item.Qte = (int)Row[2];
            item.Price = Row[3].ToString();
            Accessoires.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return Accessoires;
}
```

and use it :

```
public List<Order> AllOrders()
        {
            DataTable Table = new DataTable();
            List<Order> Orders = new List<Order>();
            Table = Browse(1, 0);
            foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows)
            {
                Order item = new Order();

                item.ID = (int)Row[0];
                item.Date = (DateTime)Row[1];
                item.Products = new List<Accessoire>();
                item.Products = Accessoires((int)Row[0]); <=== Modified here 
                item.Client = new Gestion.Garage.Modules._Client();
                item.TotalPrice = (string)Row[3];
                item.Client.ID = (int)Row[2];
                item.Client.Name = (string)Row[9];
                item.Client.Phone = (string)Row[10];
                item.Client.Email = (string)Row[11];
                item.Client.Adress = (string)Row[12];
                item.Client.Marque = (string)Row[13];
                item.Client.Model = (string)Row[14];
                item.Client.Kilometrage = (string)Row[15];
                item.Client.Anne = (string)Row[16];
                item.Client.Obvservation = (string)Row[17];
                item.AcessoireID = (int)Row[18];
                if (!Orders.Contains(item))
                {
                    Orders.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return Orders;
        }
```

Thanks to Hugan <3

Comment: I don't think you need `new DataTable()` or `if (Table.Rows.Count > 0)`.

Comment: I need to see the counts for some other checks but yea i don't need `new DataTable()` i was doing a manuel DataTable filling to check something